# Assert user input is capital letter

Tags: java, input, assert

I have to write a program where the user is supposed to enter a string.  The first and the second character have to be capital letters, and the rest have to be numbers.  If the user does not enter this correctly, the program is supposed to generate a messate informing about the imput error.

I know I could do this by writing a loop which scans every single sign in the user input and looks for mistakes.

So say I have defined:

char sign;

And I use a loop with charAt(loop number)

Can I do the scanning of capital letters in an easier way than writing, say:

```
if (sign != 'A' || sign != 'B' || sign !='C' || sign != 'D' . . . .)
```

for all letters?  This is kind of a tedious way to write the program.  So if anyone know any shortcuts/methods for asserting the input is a capital letter, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It depends on the language you are using...

Comment: Oh.  Sorry for not mentioning it.  I am using Java.

Answer (score 2):

```
ch=(char) inputstream.read();
if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
    /* DO SOMETHING */
}
else {
    /* DO SOMETHING ELSE*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
if(sign >= 'A' && sign <= 'Z')
```

This is true if sign is a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regular expression](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) on the whole string instead of testing character by character.

```
if (!userString.matches("^[A-Z]{2}\d+$") {
    // Generate a warning...
}
```

What this regex does is force the start of the string to be two capital letters, then followed by at least one digit to the end of the string.

If you wanted to do loop code like you suggest, then use the `Character.isUppercase(char c)` [method in the Java libraries](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) to test if the letter is uppercase. Likewise, you can use `Character.isDigit(char c)` to test for a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
if Sign = Uppercase(Sign) then
  DoSomethingIfItIsUppercase;

// Say Sign was "j", the Uppercase(); will make it "J", and then they dont match.
// But if Sign was "J", Uppercase(); would still make it "J", and they would match.
```

Would that work?

Note: This is Delphi, as you did not specify what language you are using ;)

Here's a Java Example (Untested!):

```
  char Char1 = yourinput.charAt(0);
  char Char2 = yourinput.charAt(1);
  // Those were the first to characters
  // Now check if they are uppercase
  if(Char1==Character.toUpperCase(Char1) && Char2==Character.toUpperCase(Char2))
  {
    // Do something if both are uppercase
  }
```

Comment: I believe both Patrik & I's suggestions will work - pick whichever suits you best! Since Patrik's answer uses only operators, I'd say his answer would be best :)